# How can I use onchange attribute with symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

I'am using symfony 1.4 with propel orm. I have 3 tables such as countries, states and counties. I want to use the onchange attribute to avoid overload and pass over unrelated records. How can I use onchange attribute in form classes.

Answer (score 1):

Why use it in the form class and not in you view (and use it with ajax) when rendering the field? That assuming you are not doing an `echo $form` and you are echoing each field (label, error, field). If you do an `echo $form`, you might need to write it in the form class (imo this belongs in the view, not in the class, but that's another problem). Just use the array attributes parameter with you are defining the widget. Something like:

```
$this->widgetSchema['state'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array(blabla), array('onchange' => 'someJsFunction'));
```

If you want to also restrict the choices, then, in the form classes (for example to only populate a select with the US states when US has been selected in the country selectbox), send the  context to the form as an option:

in your actions:

`$this->form = new whateverForm(array(), array('context' => $this->getContext()));`

in your form do something like:

```
$context = $this->getOption('context');

if (!$context instanceOf sfContext) throw new sfException('whateverForm needs the context.. bla bla');

$taintedValues = $context->getRequest($this->getName()); 
$country = $taintedValues['country'];`
```

That will get you the current submited country to display the states only for that country.

Same thing with the counties.